# Excel - Return list of row results based off searching a keyword in a column with multiple words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I looked at other similar questions and their answers hadn't pertained to mine specifically, or I just missed it.

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns: **Email, Fname, Lname, and Group**. In the group column, there are up 7 different keywords that may or may not be in that cell. An example would be something like:

```
|email@email.com|John|Smith|Apple, Banana, Sauce, Kitten
```

Now I have over 30,000 rows, some rows just have Apple, some just have Sauce, and some have a combination of more than just one.

How can I search the Group column, and return a list of all those rows that contain apple. Or a list that contains all those who have Kitten in that list.

I know this seems like a simple request, but I am clueless when it comes to Excel, and a lot of what I see, I can't get to work.

I have tried using VLOOKUP, but that only returns a single entry from what I can see. I can't understand using Index. Just looking for some guidance and maybe a formula or two.

Comment: Can't you just apply filters to the column headers and type the group you are looking for?

Comment: @Jordan I wouldn't know how to do that, and anytime I searched that never came up as a solution. If you feel like it, could you elaborate more on how one would do that?

Comment: click on any cell in your data.  go the data tab.  Click the Filter.  Little triangle will appear in the top row.  Click on the arrow in your Group column.  And type in the input box `Apple` or anything else you want to search.  It will filter on that and bring up only those that have `Apple` in the field whether alone or with other.

Comment: Or Google Advanced Filter, which will allow you to create the list in a separate area or sheet.

Comment: Thank you both @ScottCraner and Jordan - shortly after I tried it, and it would work, but not completely. Thank you though as that bit will help me in the future, I can already tell. Thanks for helping out an Excel noob :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next column over.....

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH('apple',GROUP))` will look in your cell to see if apple is in the cell at all.  You can use this to assist in your queries:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text)), "Yes", "No")`: an example of using it in a iF string.

Comment: This is working quite well. This is what I was looking for. I can easily sort the column aftewards based on True/False. Thank you, you literally saved my day!